# Laravel - category navigation routing errors

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

Currently, I'm writing an e-commerce application based on Laravel. The primary navigation structure of my project is the following:

- Home (/)
- Category 1 (e.g. /cars)
- Category 2 (e.g. /cars/volkswagen)
- Category 3 (e.g. /cars/volkswagen/golf)

The model's name is 'Category' and the controller is 'CategoryController'. Model table is produced with **migration**:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('parent_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

For this purpose I created the following **routes in web.php**:

```
Route::get('/{category1}', 'CategoryController@category1');

Route::get('/{category1}/{category2}', 'CategoryController@category2');

Route::get('/{category1}/{category2}/{category3}', 'CategoryController@category3');
```

This is my **CategoryController**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category as CategoryModel;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function category1(CategoryModel $category1)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }

    public function category2(CategoryModel $category1, CategoryModel $category2)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }

    public function category3(CategoryModel $category1, CategoryModel $category2, CategoryModel $category3)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

Finally, pages like localhost/cars/volkswagen/golf can be opened. The problem is if I request localhost/golf in my browser the server delivers me the page. That page is not what I want. This page should only be via localhost/cars/volkswagen/golf.

**Do you have some advice how to solve this problem?**

**Edit1: I still want to have the pages /category1/ and /category1/category2/ delivered. This pages display an overview of the available products.**

Comment: Have you verified which function it's actually going through? Try `Log::info(__FUNCTION__);` as the first line of each function, then check your log after browsing to that page.

Comment: @aynber It's going through all of the functions:

[2017-09-01 05:50:24] local.INFO: category1  
[2017-09-01 05:50:30] local.INFO: category2  
[2017-09-01 05:50:35] local.INFO: category3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. To avoid, that the different categories can be entered into the "wrong" part of the URL I have to define my own resolution logic in the boot method of the RouteServiceProvider. This is called [**Route Model Binding**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding).

This is the code insinde the RouteServiceProvider that works for my project:

```
public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        Route::bind('cytegory1', function ($value) {
            return Category::where('name', $value)->where('parent_id', 0)->first();
        });

        Route::bind('category2', function ($value) {

            $category2 = Category::where('name', $value)->first();

            // Check if level 2

            if($category2->parent_id == 0) {
                // 1st level -> 404 error
                abort(404);
            } else {
                // level 2 or 3

                // get parent object 
                $parent_id= $category2->parent_id;
                $parent = Category::where('id', $parent_id)->first();
                    if($parent->parent_id == 0){
                        // level 2
                        return Category::where('name', $value)->first();
                    } else {
                        // level 3
                        abort(404);
                        return false;
                    }
            }

        });

        Route::bind('category3', function ($value) {

            $category3= Category::where('name', $value)->first();

            // check if level 1

            if($category3->parent_id == 0) {
                // 1st level -> 404 Fehler
                abort(404);
            } else {
                // level 2 or 3

                // get parent object
                $parent_id= $category3->parent_id;
                $parent = Category::where('id', $parent_id)->first();
                    if($parent->parent_id == 0){
                        // level 2
                        abort(404);
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        // level 3
                        return Category::where('name', $value)->first();
                    }
            }

        });
    }
```

Imagine the final url like localhost/cars/volkswagen/golf. In the database the cars is defined as category 1 (id = 1, parent_id = 0), volkswagen is defined as category 2 (id = 2, parent_id = 1) and golf is defined as category 3 (id = 3, parent_id = 2).

**Edit1:**

As the url pattern is localhost/category1/category2/category3 I can only enter cars as a value for category 1. The same is valid for volkswagen as category 2 and golf as category 3. If I try to enter one of these:

- localhost/volkswagen or
- localhost/golf or
- localhost/cars/golf

the application is responding with a 404 error. This is the expected behaviour. 
Please give me your comments for further improvement.

Answer (score 0):

As you have created three different routes:

```
Route::get('/{category1}', 'CategoryController@category1');

Route::get('/{category1}/{category2}', 'CategoryController@category2');

Route::get('/{category1}/{category2}/{category3}', 'CategoryController@category3');
```

whenever you pass one parameter, its matching route i.e. First one will be executed, same happens if you pass two parameters.

If you want, this route will work only with three parameters, remove the first two routes and keep only that route which have 3 route parameters  in it.

Comment: I still want to have the pages /category1/ and  /category1/category2/ delivered, so I need them or not? This pages display an overview of the available products.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem "The problem is if I request localhost/golf in my browser the server delivers me the page." write the route of category 1 this way since for category1 the parent_id is 0 and we can write the validation to pass this route:

```
Route::get('category/{category1}', function(App\Category $category1)
{
    if ($category1->parent_id==0)
    {
        return (new App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController)->category1($category1);
    }

});
```